# Apex cpu time limit exceeded with this code ! any solutions please

Tags: apex

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contract> scope) {
   if(system.isFuture()) return;
    List<contract> listContractToUpdate = [SELECT id, Tech_date_inferieur_la_plus_proche__c, Tech_date_de_reference__c, (Select id, DateFacture__c from Factures__r WHERE DateFacture__c <> NULL) from Contract where Status <>'Facturation terminée' ];
    
    for (Contract contract : listContractToUpdate) {
        Date dateMinLaPlusProche = Null ;
        Date dateDeReference= contract.Tech_date_de_reference__c;
        String idContract = contract.Id;
        contract c1 = new contract();
       //List <ProformaFacture__c> factures = [Select id, DateFacture__c from ProformaFacture__c WHERE Contrat__r.Id=: contract.Id and DateFacture__c <> NULL and DateFacture__c <: dateDeReference  limit 1 ];
        //System.debug('liste des FACTURES'+factures);
        for (ProformaFacture__c facture : contract.Factures__r) {
            System.debug('IdContract'+idContract);
            System.debug('dateDeReference'+dateDeReference);
            System.debug('DateFacture__c'+facture.DateFacture__c);
            
            if ((facture.DateFacture__c <> NULL) && (facture.DateFacture__c < dateDeReference)){
                If ((DateMinLaPlusProche < facture.DateFacture__c) || (DateMinLaPlusProche ==Null)){
                    DateMinLaPlusProche = facture.DateFacture__c;
                    System.debug('DateMinLaPlusProche'+DateMinLaPlusProche);
                }
                
                c1.Tech_date_inferieur_la_plus_proche__c= DateMinLaPlusProche;                                        
                break;
                
            }
            
        }
        
        contract.Tech_date_inferieur_la_plus_proche__c= c1.Tech_date_inferieur_la_plus_proche__c;
        System.debug('!!!!!!contract.Tech_date_inferieur_la_plus_proche__c=!!!!!' + contract.Tech_date_inferieur_la_plus_proche__c);
    }
    
     try {  
         update listContractToUpdate;
     System.debug(' update listContractToUpdate; WREERERYYYYYYY' + listContractToUpdate);}
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug('error to update' + e);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You not using [Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) correctly. When implementing the `Batchable` interface, there are three methods you need to implement `start`, `execute`, and `finish`. The `start` method is where you set up your query, not the `execute` method. The `List<Contract> scope` parameter of the `execute` method would hold all the results of the query, but split into batches. The nested loop probably isn't helping either. You might consider restructuring things like this:

```
public class BatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
  // This method is used to retrieve the data you want to update
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    // query for contracts here and store all their ids
    Set<Id> contractIds;

    // set up a query for ProformaFacture__c as a string here
    String query = 'SELECT Id FROM ProformaFacture__c WHERE Contrat__c IN :contractIds' ;

    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
  }
 
  // use this to update data
  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<ProformaFacture__c> batch) {
     // the batch parameter contains a batch of of the data setup in the start method. 
     // By default it will be 200 records.
    
     // do all the updates here. 
  }
 
  // Use this for anything you want to happen when the job is finish. Often used to 
  //send out error or success emails.
  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    
    
  }
}
```